# Elisp programmatically copy to clipboard clipboard

Tags: emacs, clipboard, copy-paste

I am trying to copy the result some elisp code execution to my clipboard.
I am looking for something that i could use like that.

```
(defun generate-string-to-my-clipboard ()
  (magic-function (foo-generate-string)))
```

After execution, i would be able to paste in my system the result of (foo-generate-string)

I have seen solution using `kill-region` or `clipboard-kill-ring-save`, but it needs a region or the string somewhere in a buffer, to select it. It could work, but feel a little far fetched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `kill-new`:

```
(kill-new "this is copied to clipboard")
```

(Assuming that `x-select-enable-clipboard` is set to its default value `t`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it without affecting the `kill-ring` and without depending on the value of `select-enable-clipboard` (i.e. *only* export it to the clipboard for other applications to use), you can do:

```
(gui-set-selection 'CLIPBOARD "copied to clipboard from Emacs")
```